# Unable to run su in adb shell on an Ubuntu machine

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rooting, adb, linux

Device: Unbranded Android tablet
Android: 2.2

I was trying to root my tablet using my Ubuntu 11.10 machine.

I followed the following instructions from a site:

```
1. adb Install Superuser.apk
2. adb push busybox /sdcard/
3. adb push su /sdcard/
```

In the same terminal, now we open adb:

```
adb shell
```

Enter the command for superuser

```
su
```

Now, you will copy and paste these commands:

```
1. mount -o remount,rw /system
2. mv /system/xbin/su /system/xbin/oldsu
3. cp /sdcard/busybox /system/bin/busybox
4. cp /sdcard/su /system/bin/su
5. chmod 06755 /system/bin/su
6. chmod 0755 /system/bin/busybox
7. ln -s /system/bin/su /system/xbin/su
8. exit su (may say something about a bad number
9. exit
10. adb reboot
```

I could not run the first mount command, but still continued with rest of the 9 commands. Then, I ran a root checker app after reboot to check whether my device was rooted. It indicated no root access.

I then again ran adb shell, and then on running su, it gave an error:

```
su: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Now, I am not even able to delete this file. I am stuck and since it's my first time trying to root an Android device. I have no idea what should be done now to resolve this problem and successfully root my device.

Comment: Off topic, this is a common shell scripting problem and not Android-related at all. Step 8 is not a command but a comment, you probably forgot the '#' in front of it. Or just omit step 8. Even if you try to execute step 8, step 9 will run anyway. No problem here.

Comment: @ce4 But he's not able to run the first mount command. What could be the problem with that?

Comment: If he cannot run the first command, the following ones should fail as well. Besides, how should that work? Immediately after `adb shell` he issues `su` – which is not yet there. Not being root, `mount` cannot work, so the stuff cannot be copied to the `/system` partition. What confuses me a little is step 2 – which implies there is a `su` available already before rooting. I never checked that; is that the case? So one could get root permissions via ADB on a not-rooted device? I doubt that, since why then do we need exploits to root devices?

Comment: It could be one of those pre-rooted tablets, but why would be there a guide to root an already rooted device...?

Comment: Before doing this all, when i ran su in adb shell, # was coming. But now an error is coming. Is there any way that i can do something about that file?

Comment: And if initially # was coming, did that mean that it was already rooted ? Because when i ran a terminal app, it was not taking the su command.

Comment: A `#` at the shell means you are root, exactly. So, as Shywim already wondered, why did you want to root a rooted device? Makes no sense. To undo your changes, you need to become root first – which you just broke. Try `oldsu` instead of `su` to become root, it might well be it's just the "new `su`" being incompatible somehow.

Comment: To close-voters: Why should this be an "Android independent phone question"? OP broke root on his device, and this question is about how to restore it. A perfectly fine Android question IMHO, and also on-topic. Has nothing to do with Ubuntu, the problem is on the Android device.

Comment: @Izzy I tried running oldsu. It shows #. Thanks for the tip:) What should i do next?I want to upgrade my tablet from 2.2 to a newer version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the `su` binary you installed does not work well with your system. As you luckily created a backup of the original `su` executable, recommendation is to revert the incompatible changes first:

```
adb shell
$ oldsu
# mount -o remount,rw /system
# rm /system/xbin/su /system/bin/su
# cp /system/xbin/oldsu /system/xbin/su
# exit
$ exit
adb reboot
```

Explanation: Start `adb shell` and become root (using the working `oldsu` executable). Delete `/system/xbin/su` (which is only a symlink now) and the incompatible `/system/bin/su`, then copy the working `su` back to where it belongs. Then exit the root shell and finally adb shell. The reboot is optional, and should not be needed. Also optionally you could remove `busybox` (or keep it if it works). Before exiting `adb shell` you might wish to test whether `su` works again, just to be sure (which is why I wrote `cp` for this: if anything goes wrong, you still have your `oldsu` available).

With those steps, you should at least have everything in working order again, and *this* issue is solved. Updating to a newer Android version is a separate issue: Please check the [update](/questions/tagged/update) tag, as corresponding questions already exist. Same for the ROM you might need (check the [rom](/questions/tagged/rom) tag for that, and in also check the tag-wikis for [update](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/update/info) and [rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info)).